# How to get maximum and minimum data from array of dates

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have list of dates like below.

```
var dates = ['05/02/2015', '12/03/2014', '05/02/2012', '05/02/2013'];
```

I try below but not working

```
var maximumDate = Math.max.apply(Math, dates);
```

Comment: Hint: Those are strings.

Comment: I know that's why asking for any solution.

Comment: don't know why get down vote on this question

Answer (score 3):

You have an array of strings. You'd need to parse them into dates to be able to use Math.max, for example:

```js
var dates = ['05/02/2015', '12/03/2014', '05/02/2012', '05/02/2013'];
alert(new Date(Math.max.apply(Math, dates.map(Date.parse))));
```

This maps all strings to a millisecond number since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC. Then we apply the `Math.max` to those numbers, and create a new `Date` object from the result.

For this to work, you'd need to ensure that your strings are in [an expected format for Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#ECMAScript_5_ISO-8601_format_support). If they aren't, it will fall back to an implementation-specific parse which may produce unexpected results. You can use a date library like [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) to create date objects from these strings.

Comment: Thanks...it help too much.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.max` expects numbers as arguments, so therefore the comparison of string values don't really make sense, that's why your sample returns `NaN`.

I suggest converting the string values to `Date` objects and comparing their time value instead.

```
var dates = [ '05/02/2015', '12/03/2014', '05/02/2012', '05/02/2013' ];

// maximum universal time value
var maximumTime = Math.max.apply( null, 
    // convert time strings to universal time
    dates.map( function(d) {
        return new Date( d ).getTime( )
    } ) 
);

// date representation of that time
var maximumDate = new Date( maximumTime );
```